# Reading and writing structs remotely

Tags: c++, struct, embedded, arm, protocol-buffers

I'm currently building a robot which has some sensors attached to it. The control unit on the robot is an ARM Cortex-M3, all sensors are attached to it and it is connected via Ethernet to the "ground station".

Now I want to read and write settings on the robot via the ground station. Therefore I thought about implementing a "virtual register" on the robot that can be manipulated by the ground station.

It could be made up of structs and look like this:

```
// accelerometer register
struct accel_reg {
  // accelerations
  int32_t accelX;
  int32_t accelY;
  int32_t accelZ;
};

// infrared distance sensor register 
struct ir_reg {
  uint16_t  dist; // distance
};

// robot's register table
struct {
  uint8_t     status;         // current state
  uint32_t    faultFlags;     // some fault flags
  accel_reg   accelerometer;  // accelerometer register
  ir_reg      ir_sensors[4];  // 4 IR sensors connected
} robot;

// usage example:

robot.accelerometer.accelX = -981;
robot.ir_sensors[1].dist = 1024;
```

On the robot the registers will be constantly filled with new values and configuration settings are set by the ground station and applied by the robot.

The ground station and the robot will be written in C++ so they both can use the same struct datatype.

**The question** I have now is how to encapsulate the read/write operations in a protocol without writing tons of meta data?

Let's say I want to read the register `robot.ir_sensors[2].dist`. How would I address this register in my protocol?

I already thought about transmitting a relative offset in bytes (i.e the relative position in memory inside the struct) but I think memory alignment and padding may cause problems, especially because the ground station runs on a x86_64 architecture and the robot runs on a 32-bit ARM processor.

Thanks for any hints! :)

Comment: I was going to suggest [Google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), but you have already tagged the question with those. Is there a reason for NOT using them?

Comment: Hi, at first glance it didn't look like it would run on an ARM Cortex M3 but I just discovered that there is an embedded version of it!

Comment: I've successfully run GPB on a variety of embedded devices, including ARM. That is what I would do, unless there was some gotcha.

Comment: Unless the ground station is an ARM also, you need to worry about alignment and endian issues.  Do you want to read and write all data as a unit, or pick and choose individual values?

Comment: Endian issues are taken care of by the GPB code. That's why Google developed it.

Comment: Did you use "Protobuf-Embedded-C"? Are data types like uint16 supported?

Comment: I want to read/write individual values, and registers (like IR sensor data, accelerometer data) can be grouped into data streams which are transmitted on regular interval.

Comment: Endian issues shouldn't matter, both are `little endian`; at least it is odd to run ARMs in `big endian`.  However, structure alignment will always be an issue.  Having `endian` independence is a nice plus. So this question was answered by the **tags**?  That is ironic.

Comment: the problem still remains that I'd like to read/write entries individually, the thing is I'd like to group certain fields into a data stream dynamically... The size and name of each field is known on both sides, it's just about how to address certain fields with as little overhead as possible.

Comment: Use the property pattern, with indexes on fields?

Comment: Using structs across compile domains is generally a bad idea, period maintenance is required for the life of the software. (where other solutions dont have that problem).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think the [Google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) are an excellent session/presentation layer tool to use.</strike>  Actually, Google protocol buffers do not support the syntax I am thinking of.  So, I will change this part of my answer to recommend [**XSD**](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) by Code Synthesis.  Although it is primarily used with XML, it supports different presentation layers such as [*XDR*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) and may be more efficient than *protocol buffers* with large amounts of optional data.  The generate code is also very nice to work with.  **XSD** is free to use with OpenSource software and even commercial use with limited message structures.

I don't believe you want to read/write register sets at random.  You can prefix a message with an `enum` that denotes a message such as, `IR update`, `distance`, `accel`, etc.  These are register groups.  Then the robot responds with the register set.  All the registers you've given so far are sensors.  The `write` ones must be motor control?

You want to think about what control you want to perform and the type of telemetry you would like to receive.  Then come up with a message structure and bundle the information together.  You could use `sequence diagrams`, and remote procedure API's like [SOA/SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture), [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), etc.  I don't mean these RPC frameworks directly, but the concepts such as `request/response` and perhaps message that are just sent periodically (telemetry) without specific requests.   So there would be a *telemetry* request from the ground station with some sort of interval and then the robot would respond periodically with unsolicited data.  You always need a message id (`enum` above), unless your protocol is going to be stateful, which  I would discourage for robustness reasons.

You haven't described how the control system might work or if you wish to do this remotely.  Describing that may lead to more ideas on the protocol.  I believe we are talking about layers 5,6,7 of [OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).  Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also going to suggest Google Protocol Buffers.

In the simplest case, you could implement one message `RobotState` like this:

```
message RobotState {
   optional int32_t status = 1;
   optional int32_t distance = 2;
   optional int32_t accelX = 3;
   ...
}
```

Then when the robot receives the message, it will take new values from any optional field that is present. It will then reply with a message containing the current value of all fields.

This way it is quite easy to implement field update using the "merge message" functionality of most protobuf implementations. Also you can keep it very simple at start because you only  have one message type, but if you need to expand later you can add submessages.

It is true that protobuf does not support `int8_t` or `int16_t`. Just use `int32_t` instead.

Comment: +1 Although at some point, I think the `optional` overhead will reach (and maybe exceed) the use of a *message id*.  Basically eight optionals should be the same as a byte wide *message id*, if I have guessed how optionals are implemented correctly with google protocol buffers.

Comment: @artlessnoise If you want to group the optionals as message types, make them as submessages. Then the overhead of the optional submessage is the same as your message id would be.

Comment: Right, I think that either way you can structure the messages in some way, to reduce the overhead.  The important point is that message structure **will** reduce the overhead.  The OP wants low overhead, yet seems to want to *read/write* at random; I think those goals conflict, which is part of my answer.  I guess I have *protocol buffers* don't support what I am thinking of.  This is *literally* true.  I don't know enough about them.  I thought that maybe *sub-messages* were possible, but I couldn't find documentation on how *optional* or *submessages* are encoded.